# select only distinct value from one column

Tags: sql, select, distinct, sybase, sap-ase

I am displaying three fields from my query, and I want to display a distinct banking_no. I still want to display the other fields even they are not distinct. Please help.

```
SELECT  C.RECEIPT_OFFICE_PREFIX, B.BANKING_NO, B.STATUS_CD
FROM    TControl B, TComponent C
WHERE   C.DEPOSIT_BANK_ACCT = 'xxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx'
AND     B.BANKING_NO = C.BANKING_NO
AND     B.COMPANY_ID = C.COMPANY_ID
AND     B.RECEIPT_OFFICE_PREFIX = C.RECEIPT_OFFICE_PREFIX
AND     B.STATUS_CD != 'C'
ORDER BY B.BANKING_NO
```

I am using Sybase ASE 12.5

Comment: That is not possible, unless you somehow hint the database to select the record you intended. And which is not possible as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More recent versions of Sybase support `row_number()`.  You would use it in a subquery like this:

```
SELECT RECEIPT_OFFICE_PREFIX, BANKING_NO, STATUS_CD
FROM (SELECT C.RECEIPT_OFFICE_PREFIX, B.BANKING_NO, B.STATUS_CD,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B.BANKING_NO ORDER BY B.BANKING_NO) as seqnum
      FROM TControl B JOIN
           TComponent C
           ON B.BANKING_NO = C.BANKING_NO AND B.COMPANY_ID = C.COMPANY_ID
      WHERE C.DEPOSIT_BANK_ACCT = 'xxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx' AND     
            B.RECEIPT_OFFICE_PREFIX = C.RECEIPT_OFFICE_PREFIX AND
            B.STATUS_CD != 'C'
    ) BC
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY BANKING_NO;
```

Comment: I am using Sybase 12.50 and my DBSolo does not recognize OVER.

Comment: That also doesn't support `rowid`. You can do this if the tables have a primary key.

Answer (score 0):

What you want may not be called distint. If the rest of data is the same just using a DISTINCT will do. However if data may be different you need to tell what result should the database choose. the first row? the last row?

If you do not mind just use;

```
SELECT DISTINCT  MAX(C.RECEIPT_OFFICE_PREFIX), B.BANKING_NO, MAX(B.STATUS_CD)
FROM    TControl B, TComponent C
WHERE   C.DEPOSIT_BANK_ACCT = 'xxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx'
AND     B.BANKING_NO = C.BANKING_NO
AND     B.COMPANY_ID = C.COMPANY_ID
AND     B.RECEIPT_OFFICE_PREFIX = C.RECEIPT_OFFICE_PREFIX
AND     B.STATUS_CD != 'C'
GROUP BY B.BANKING_NO
```

In you need to choose one row use Gordon solution.

Comment: Distinct did the work. I created 4 transactions with varying column entries and the script worked.